# Aptana Studio 3 CSS folding

Tags: css, aptana

Css code folding doesn't seem to be there any more Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.0.2.201106082310.

I have checked the preferences under 'Aptana', 'Editors', 'CSS' and 'Enable Folding' has a tick in it.

Folding works fine for JS but seems to have dissappeared under CSS, intellisense still works fine.

I used to get a little '-' or a '+' symbol in the left column alongside the line number.

Anybody else found this problem, its a great tool and would like to be able to use it again.

Comment: I wish I could downvote close votes. Absolutely ludicrous to see people still voting to move this kind of question to Super User when they're perfectly fine for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely still available, as I can see it  in 3.0.2 or 3.0.3.

It might be that your code has a parse error or some similar problem that's causing the ticks not to show, though that would be odd if it happens to all files.

If it is a single file, I would file a bug [here](http://www.aptana.com/redirect/bugs). Otherwise, you might check Help > Studio > View Log File to see if there are any error messages, or try updating to the latest beta version, 3.0.3 ([docs on the wiki](http://www.aptana.com/redirect/docs))

Comment: sorry--early morning typing. Edited.

Comment: Thanks Ingo from your suggestion(log file & parse error) I have narrowed it down to a problem opening a CSS which contains a !Important note captial 'I' works fine with a lowercase 'i'. Didn't think css was case sensistive for commands.